# Problems in calculating and printing long unsigned integers

Tags: atmega2560, mathematics

I have this code which provides an erroneous unsigned long number.

CODE:

```cpp
char buff[100];

int unsigned long bytes;

bytes = 48 * 70 * 144;

sprintf(buff,"%lu bytes\n", bytes);

BTPort.print(buff);
```

OUTPUT:
20088 bytes

BUT: The correct value is 483840

Answer (score 2):

This is because the default numeric type is `int`, which on Arduino is just 16 bits (and signed).

So 48 * 70 * 144 is 0x76200 in hex, which truncated to 16 bits is 0x6200, or 25088. This calculation is done by the preprocessor, not the compiler, so doesn't know (or care) about the destination variable type.

You need to force the values to be calculated as unsigned long by appending `UL` to them:

```cpp
bytes = 48UL * 70UL * 144UL;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, this was extremely useful.

Comment: It's even sufficient to force one of the values to be unsigned long. `bytes = 48UL*20*144;`